# Is $\mathbb{R}$ a Borel set?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

Is the set of all real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, a Borel set? If yes, how can this be proved? I know that all closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are Borel sets, but can this fact be used to prove that $\mathbb{R}$, a Borel set? Also, I think I can show that $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on itself (if that is meaningful), but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed (and open, for that matter) subset of itself.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Could you pleas explain how $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of itself?  The complement of $\mathbb{R}$ is just $\emptyset$, and I'm not sure if $\emptyset$ is open.

Comment: The empty set is always open by the definition of a topology.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson In every topological space, $\emptyset$ and the whole space are both closed and open; that's part of the definition (check your text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are starting from real analysis without the definition of 'a topology' you can use as a definition of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, or more generally in a metric space, that a set $O$ is open if for all $x\in O$ there is a ball $B_r(x)\subseteq O$ for some $r>0$. For the empty set this is vacuously true (there are no $x$ to quantify over, so you can't find one to disprove the universal) therefore $\emptyset$ is open which means $\mathbb{R}$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the **definition** of a sigma algebra on a set $X$ is that $X$ itself belongs to it. In particular, $\mathbb{R}$ belongs to the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

Also, by the definition of a topology, any topological space is both open and closed in itself. So $\mathbb{R}$ is also closed in itself.